# Ajax does not delete a row in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm using DataTables in Laravel, and my goal is to delete a row from database and then reload the list of data. But for some reason it does not work. I receive - `Data Not Deleted` error, and also `setTimeOut` function seems to not work, because a message does not disappear. I'm a newcomer to Ajax so it's hard for me to find the reason of what is wrong. Button:

```
                    $button = '   <button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-fw  fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>';
```

HTML form that appears when a delete button is clicked:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="post" id="sample_form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Confirmation</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 align="center" style="margin:0;">Are you sure you want to remove this data?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="btn btn-danger">OK</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
        var employee_id;

        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
            employee_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
        });

        $('#ok_button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"/admin/employees/destroy/"+employee_id,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#ok_button').text('Deleting...');
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#employee_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    alert('Data Deleted');
                    }, 2000);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#employee_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    alert('Data Not Deleted');
                    }, 2000);
            },
            })
        });
    });
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/admin/employees/destroy/{id}', [EmployeeController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Controller function:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $data = Employee::findOrFail($id);
        $data->delete();
    }
```

Comment: Does the button text change to "Deleting..." successfully?

Comment: @Andrew yes it does and it remains there even when I'm clicking on the deletion of other rows

Comment: "_it's hard for me to find the reason of what is wrong_" - as a starting point, you can print the Ajax error message to your browser's console using `console.log( error );`. Put this line inside your `error: function(xhr, status, error) { ... }` function, before `setTimeout(...)`. (Browser tools are usually displayed by hitting F12.)

Comment: Yes definitely print the Ajax response. Is the row successfully deleted? Is that your entire controller function? Are you returning anything from the controller?

Comment: @andrewJames I receive this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` although it loads a right path  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/employees/destroy/2`

Comment: @Andrew when it comes to the destroy function that is my entire function right there

Comment: go to your apache errors and see what the problem is.

Comment: DadoH has a good point below but there are a number of functional issues at play here and I think this is beyond the scope of a SO question to achieve what you're trying to do 'properly'. I strongly recommend you look up a guide or tutorial perhaps on a CRUD system with Laravel and jQuery. That being said, it sounds like it's not making it to the controller method. Try putting a `dd($id);` at the beginning of your controller's destroy method to see if you're making it to the controller and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In 'form' you have method POST, but in Route, you have it as Get.

I would try put following under  tag:

```
<form method="post" id="sample_form" class="form-horizontal">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
..
```

Or perhaps add following to ajax call, instead of @csrf and @method:

```
type: 'DELETE',
```

Then ammend Route from Get to Delete:

```
Route::Delete('/admin/employees/destroy/{id}', [EmployeeController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Comment: tried it, still the same thing is happening

Answer (score 0):

change your `<form>` `method="post"` to `method="get"`

also you forgot use `@csrf` token indside from

also change the query in controller

```
Employee::where('id',$id)->delete();
return response()->json([
    'success' => 'Record has been deleted successfully!'
]);
```

for set time out you can use this like

```
setTimeout("alert(data.success)", 3000);
```